# Site Navigation using Managed Metadata Term Store using SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, audience-targeting, managed-navigation

There are multiple lists in my site collection. And for these lists, there are multiple SharePoint Groups who can access the lists depending on the list permissions.

Depending on the Logged In user I want the Lists to be accessed. How is this possible using Managed Metadata Term store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Managed Metadata is not security trimmed or use Target Audience.. In this case you will need to write your custom Navigation Provider/Control..

Or use the Structural Navigation with Target Audience..

Comment: How do we Custom Navigation Provider/Control? Any out of box or Javascript approach is there? I need to implement on O365.